# php arguments international characters and if statements

Tags: php, string, input, char

I think I'm missing something simple with input arguments and them having characters with accent marks. I have a php file that can take arguments `example.com/myphpfile.php?ar1=somestring` and I cycle through the characters in `arg1` to do stuff and when I use characters with accent marks, it doesn't seem to work correctly. If I have `arg1=niño` my if statements don't seem to work and it is set up like this to go through:

```
$strArr = str_split($_GET['arg1']);
foreach ($strArr as &$char) {
    // do some stuff for each character       
}
```

If I use `echo $_GET['arg1'];` and use `arg1=niño`, I get `niÃ±o`. Am I doing something wrong with each character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot handle multibyte characters correctly using naïve PHP string handling functions. You need to handle them using encoding-aware functions, likely from [the mb_ family of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php). Read this to get all the details (it's long): [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Thank you. This is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

See your screen if the HTML tag  the charset parameter is ISO-8859-1 if you do not have to add and also look at your bank when it was created as it is ISO-8859-1.